# Aws Cloud9 for C++

Tags: c++, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

Why can't I run my C++ code by creating another folder. The moment I store my c++ file in a folder , the complier states no such file is in directory. But i can run my java file from other folders. Anyone ?

[This is the error I get running from the run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWJa2.png)

But the same file can be compiled and run through the terminal.

[the program can be run through the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DavyV.png)

Comment: Maybe compile your code?

Comment: I'm sure you can run your C++ code from a different folder. You just have to find the right way to tell Cloud9 that code is in a different folder.

Comment: ec2-user:~/environment/my-app/src/data structures $ make try1
g++     try1.cpp   -o try1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [try1] Error 1                                                //well this is the error i get when i wanted to compile the file from a different folder other than main

Comment: okay guys I can rude it from the terminal but I can't run it from the terminal by compiling it myself and running it myself but i can't run it using the run information. Anyone ?

Comment: What is exactly not working, can you show us exactly the command you use to compile?

Comment: @Chelmy88 yeah I've edited the post.

Comment: Unix tooling is famously bad at dealing with spaces in path and/or file names.

Comment: @Botje dude ur a fuckin legend , but wut I don't get is I use the same name spaces for my java folder and it works there.

Comment: That is up to the language support in this "cloud9" thing.

Comment: So the issue was the space?

Comment: @Chelmy88  yeah , it was the space